# getting a class of two class with attr in input, how is it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr, jquery-effects

i have two class, i want getting with attr first class in input. how is it?

> classes:
>   1.autocomplete
>   2.date

```
<input class="autocomplete date">
$('input').attr(class) 
//output 'autocomplete date' i want output this: 'autocomplete '
```

With respect.

Comment: Have you heard of the split method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the string on whitespace and select the first element of the result:

```
$("input").attr("class").split(" ")[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
$('input').attr(class).split(' ')[0]
```

The split method will return an array of all classes, and you can use [0] to get the first element in that array.